# ascii to string swift 3 problems

Tags: swift, string, ascii

In former versions of swift the following code worked.

```
let letterString = String( UnicodeScalar( 97 ) )
print( letterString )
```

returns "a"

After upgrading to swift 3 it suggested I change to

```
let letterString = String( describing: UnicodeScalar( 97 ) )
print( letterString )
```

returns Optional("a")

Okay so i tried adding the ! operator to unwrap but it doesn't work.

```
let letterString = String( describing: UnicodeScalar( 97 ) )
print( letterString! )
```

gives error: Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? How can I get an unwrapped String value from an ascii value in Swift 3?

Comment: I would actually consider this a bug – I see no reason why the compiler shouldn't be able to infer the integer literal as a `UInt8` ([this example gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/59a198309ea99da3cce287cc62145ee3) compiles just fine). Feel free to file a bug at https://bugs.swift.org.

Comment: I went ahead and filed a bug FYI: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `String` instance that's optional. It's the `UnicodeScalar` struct. So you have to unwrap that one:

```
let letterString = String(describing: UnicodeScalar(97)!)
print(letterString)
```

An alternative is to use `UnicodeScalar`s other initializer. Then you don't need to unwrap it at all.

```
let letterString2 = String(describing: UnicodeScalar(UInt8(97)))
print(letterString)
```

Comment: Note that with the `UnicodeScalar` unwrapped, you can use the `String(_:)` initialiser, rather than `String(describing:)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is your Unicode Scalar that is wrapped in an optional. You need to unwrap that in order to print "a". Your optional value at current is literally being put into a string called 'Optional("a")'.

```
let letterString = String( describing: UnicodeScalar( 97 )! )
print( letterString )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with some convenience by using extensions:

```
extension String.UnicodeScalarView {
    public init<S: Sequence>(ascii: S) where S.Iterator.Element == UInt8 {
        var _self = String.UnicodeScalarView()
        _self.append(contentsOf: ascii.map(UnicodeScalar.init))
        self = _self
    }

    public init(ascii: UInt8...) {
        self.init(ascii: ascii)
    }
}

extension String {
    public init(ascii: UInt8...) {
        self = String(UnicodeScalarView(ascii: ascii))
    }
}

let letterString = String(ascii: 97)
```

The first initializer takes any sequence of `UInt8` values and creates `String.UnicodeScalarView` out of them.

The second and third are just a convenience shortcuts to allow things like:

```
let abc = String(ascii: 97, 98, 99) // "abc"
```